# Dynamic padding of elements below nav-bar fixed-top for small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-position

I use a navbar which extends in height for small window size due to the wrapping of the text logo (which is wanted). how can I dynamically change the padding for the jumbotron below, so it is not partially covered by the navbar for small window size (when the text logo is shown in several lines). (or any better solution)

Relevante HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-text" href="./index.html">
            <span class="color-human">Logo Logo</span> <span class="color-education">Text Text</span> <span class="color-project">Snippet</span>
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link active " href="#">Item 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron feature">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .logo-text {
  white-space: normal;
}

body {
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ichbinfranz/o19s3k4L/4/)

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use Javascript/jQuery and `toggleClass()` a class on the jumbotron with extra padding when you click on the *menu-toggle*. I don't think it's possible in CSS. Maybe someone else will prove me wrong :)

Comment: Good question, but I think it's a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465130/css-a-fixed-position-div-with-dynamic-content-how-to-position-another-div-und .. not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465130/) there's no way to dynamically position an element below a `position:fixed` element using CSS. Basically, the navbar is removed from the DOM flow, so the jumbotron (and any other page elements) are not "aware" of the navbar size or position.

A possible workaround for you may be to use `position:sticky` (Bootstrap `sticky-top`) instead to get the effect of a fixed navbar. Then you won't need to use padding at all...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-text" href="./index.html">
            <span class="color-human">Logo Logo</span> <span class="color-education">Text Text</span> <span class="color-project">Snippet</span>
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron feature">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/EOH8sCCNnp